# How can I prevent hotlinking? (nginx)

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, hotlinking

I use nginx and I have no access to server conf.

May be with .htaccess analogue?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to the server configuration, you cannot change any settings. There is no equivalent to Apache httpd's .htaccess in nginx.

Comment: -1 Downvoting. This answer does not match the question title.

Comment: @unixman83 how is this not relative to the question? besides, you're bringing a question that's 4 years old - things usually change for that amount of time.

Answer (score 7):

```
location ~* (\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.jpeg)$ {
 valid_referers blocked www.domain.com domain.com;
 if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
 }
  root   /srv/www/domain.com/public_html;
}
```

Comment: is that for the nginx config file?

Comment: Yep, ask your server administrator.

Comment: it should be 'not blocked' in the second line.

Comment: @alfish Are you sure? Wouldn't setting `not blocked` disable the script, allowing all referrers through?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you HAVE access to the webserver:

```
location ~* (\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.png)$ {
 valid_referers none blocked www.example.com example.com;
 if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
 }
}
```

Comment: How is this really different from [Gionn's answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/91502/how-can-i-prevent-hotlinking-nginx/112710#112710) from 1.5 years ago?

Comment: How is `none` different from `blocked`? What is it's purpose of being added? i.e. How is a `no referrer` different from a `blocked` referrer?

Comment: In the `valid_referers` directive, `blocked` allows referrers that have been blocked by a firewall, `none` allows requests with no referrer. From docs "`none` means the absence of "Referer" header.
`blocked` means masked Referer header by firewall, for example, "Referer: XXXXXXX".

Comment: some browsers do not send a referrer header, so `none` is required to allow those.  apparently Firefox releases have been in this group

Answer (score 0):

joschi is right: nginx is driven by a single configuration file you can't edit. Your only possibility is to use a redirector script which says '403 Access Denied' for hotlinks and '301 Moved Permanently' for normal links.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to generate all your pages & content dynamically, and with different URLs every time, which expire after a while. That makes hotlinking impossible.

If that is not practical, you can also check referrer. If you cannot reconfigure nginx, you'll probably have to do it in a scripting language which generates the pages dynamically.