# nginx Anti-HotLinking configuration

Tags: nginx, hotlinking

I was wonder with nginx can I:

Check `if content-type == "image/x-jpeg" || content-type == "image/png" || content-type == "image/gif"`

`If true && referrer != "mysite.com" && referrer != "":` **Return a 404 result** or an image of my choice.

Update: This is a duplicate. But I could not find it ([the duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/91502/how-can-i-prevent-hotlinking-nginx)) until I posted. So I am leaving this here for others.

Comment: Well, this is almost a duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/91502/how-can-i-prevent-hotlinking-nginx